# Can openpyxl data validation handle strings including commas?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

From the documentation it looks like the list expects a string with each validation option comma separated such as:

```
   >>> # Create a data-validation object with list validation
   >>> dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Dog,Cat,Bat"', allow_blank=True)
```

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/validation.html

Is it possible with openpyxl to have a list of strings where one of the items also includes a comma?

for example I would want my validation options to be something like:

```
'"coke, large", "pepsi, medium", "sprite, small"'
```

Hopefully there's some clever way of formating the string?

I hope I've provided enough context and example, let me know if anything is unclear.

looking at the src it expects a string:

```
formula1 = NestedText(allow_none=True, expected_type=str)
```

from: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.0/openpyxl/worksheet/datavalidation.py

if I look at the xml:

input in python:

```
dv = DataValidation(type="list",
                            formula1='a,b,"dog,large"')
```

output in xml:

```
<formula1>a,b,"dog,large"</formula1>
```

Comment: The best thing is to check what Excel does.

Comment: @CharlieClark if you have something like "coke, large" in an excel cell and use it for validation it works fine. It's not clear how to have a list of options using DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Dog,Cat,Bat"')  where within the list a comma is also present. 

since formula1=''  seems to parse the commas.

do you have any approach to 'check what Excel does. '?

Comment: Open the file in a text editor on look at the source for the relevant worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use commas directly with the data validator in openpyxl. However, you can use the zipfile library to perform dot-to-comma conversion. I have posted sample code here: https://groups.google.com/g/openpyxl-users/c/1VUvS6TjwQQ